# Unoconv as apache user unable to create files

Tags: linux, apache, shell, centos7

I am using unoconv as apache user to create PDF files. It runs fine as a terminal user but when I run it as an apache user. I get errors.

```
sudo -u apache  /usr/bin/unoconv -o /home/gloryque/tmp/1431347151.pdf -f pdf /home/gloryque/tmp/8.doc
```

I am getting error

```
mkstemp("/usr/share/httpd/.execoool7VwpU") failed: Permission denied
mkstemp("/usr/share/httpd/.execooouoUVdw") failed: Permission denied
mkstemp("/usr/share/httpd/.execooopRuy27") failed: Permission denied
mkstemp("/usr/share/httpd/.execooov92dRJ") failed: Permission denied
mkstemp("/usr/share/httpd/.execoooiZZVFl") failed: Permission denied
mkstemp("/usr/share/httpd/.execooowk5LuX") failed: Permission denied
mkstemp("/usr/share/httpd/.execoooCgtDjz") failed: Permission denied
mkstemp("/usr/share/httpd/.execoooLxXy8a") failed: Permission denied
mkstemp("/usr/share/httpd/.execooo8LCvXM") failed: Permission denied
```

I am on a centos 7  Machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the following:

- use the latest version of unoconv (at least v0.7 when it is released, or the master branch from GitHub today)
- use the most recent stable release of LibreOffice (recent releases use less memory, are generally much faster and crash less)
- use the native LibreOffice python binary to run unoconv, eg. /opt/libreoffice4.4/program/python /usr/bin/unoconv -f pdf file.doc
- hardcode the python path in the unoconv script shebang, so put on the first line #!/opt/libreoffice4.4/program/python rather than #!/usr/bin/env python. (Apache/PHP usually do not set PATH, so unoconv fails)
- ensure that the user running unoconv has access to its HOME directory

If you do the above, everything should work out fine. If LibreOffice still crashes, you should take this up with the upstream project. Also beware that LibreOffice cannot handle more than one connection/client at the same time, so ideally your PHP script should properly lock and/or queue requests.

If you still have any issues, please report them to: http://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv/issues

Answer (score 2):

`unoconv` tries to write some temporary data in `/usr/share/httpd`. It obviously has no permission to do so.

In my tests (on an Ubuntu system), the `HOME` environment variable has been the crucial point. Using

```
HOME=/tmp sudo -u apache  /usr/bin/unoconv -o /home/gloryque/tmp/1431347151.pdf -f pdf /home/gloryque/tmp/8.doc
```

to temporarily set `HOME` to `/tmp` solved that issue.

The apache user also needs rights to write result data into the destination directory `/home/gloryque/tmp`.

Comment: Doing so it runs from terminal as apache user but not from php file.

I am on __CentOS 7__